# Django and postgres migration errors

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, heroku

I have created a new postgressql db in my django app within Heroku. Every time I run a migration, however, I get an error that I don't understand.

**Error:**

```
  Applying argent.0043_auto_20170322_1629...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type date to integer
LINE 1: ...LTER COLUMN "date_id" TYPE integer USING "date_id"::integer,...
```

I have removed and added the only date field I have, to no avail. I still get the same error whether the date field in my models is there or not. Any insight would be much appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
    euros = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=900, blank=True, null=True)
    euros_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    xrate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    dollars_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    daily_savings_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    daily_savings_display = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('argent:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def item_date(self):
        row_title = self.date
        return row_title

    class Meta:

        ordering = ['date']
```

**traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 215, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 513, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 674, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 119, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type date to integer
LINE 1: ...LTER COLUMN "date_id" TYPE integer USING "date_id"::integer,...
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to migrate the date column from a integer type to to a datetime one, you need to handle any existing entries you have in the table before you can run the migration.
It's likely that you already have some integers in the `date` column when you try to change the column type, so the conversion fails as postgres doesn't know how to convert an integer to a datetime.

You can either delete all your entries if you don't care about them, or otherwise you need to break you migration into separate steps:

1. Create the new datetime column with a temporary name
2. Run a data migration to convert your integers into datetimes and populate the new column
3. Drop the old integer date column, rename the new one with the final name.

Comment: It isn't that I want to convert the date column from integer to datetime. It has always been a datetime column, and there is no data in the new db. I'm transitioning from a sqlitedb to a posgresdb (sorry I didnt mention that before) and just need to write the new fields from my models.py to the new posgresdb. I have tried changing the date field to a charfield,  and get the same error when I stand up a fresh posgresdb.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out that all of my old migration.py files were throwing my initial migration on Heroku off. I deleted the old migration files within my app. my app and everything ran as it should. I'll add the answer.